# Elasticsearch count is less than indexed while using elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-hadoop

I created an index and indexed data into it using elasticsearch-hadoop-2.2. The HQL looks like this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE es_external_table (
field1 type1,
field2 type2
  ) STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler' TBLPROPERTIES (
'es.batch.size.bytes'='1mb',
'es.batch.size.entries'='0',
'es.batch.write.refresh'='false',
'es.batch.write.retry.count'='3',
'es.mapping.id'='field1',
'es.write.operation'='index',
'es.nodes'='IP:9200',
'es.nodes.discovery'='false',
'es.resource'='my_index/my_type');

insert into table es_external_table select field1, field2... from hive_table1
```

Table es_external_table is the external table and hive_table1 is the source table. I find that there are 1332561 items in hive_table1. However there is only 1332559 docs in elasticsearch. Both `_count` API and `_search?search_type=count` API return 1332559. Two docs were missing.

I usee `curl -XGET  'http://IP:9200/my_index/my_type/my_id?_source=false` to check data in Elasticsearch. And `my_id` is from hive_table1 and it is also the _id in my_index/my_type. All 1332561 return `"found":true`.

I am confused.

1. How many docs in my_index/my_type actually?
2. Why `_count` and `search_type=count`API return 1332559 if there are 1332561?
3. Which docs are missing if there are 1332559 docs?

Any suggestions？

Comment: Is it possible that some of your docs have the same ID (i.e. the same value in `field1`), in which case they would override themselves?

Comment: Yes，there exist same ID. Thanks.

Comment: That's the issue then, if you fix that you'll have the same doc count on next import.